# Google Apps Script array values are changing after a different array is changed

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I created a script that takes some data from 3 different google spreadsheets and paste them onto multiple spreadsheets. The location to paste it on is separated into 3 different sheets (overview, NL, and BE). For the overview tab, all of the spreadsheet contains the same data (prodArray), therefore I created it before the loops. For the NL and BE it uses the same logic but different source (finalArray), so I created it inside the MSF loop. Also for these 3 data, the first 4 columns are the same so I created the initArray.

However the weird thing is the prodArray changes after the first iteration of the sCount loop (the one that changes to the different spreadsheets), even though it should not be changed after entering the MSF loop. After trying to debug it I found that the value changes inside the loop that creates the finalArray. When finalArray[i][4] and [5] is inputted, for some reason the prodArray changes. Here it is the part of the code, and this is part of the [log of the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV5Uf.png)

```
Logger.log("A\n" + prodArray[i]);
    finalArray[i][4] = "=COUNTIF(F" + (i + 2) + ":AA" + (i + 2) + ";\"SELECTED\")/COUNTA(F" + (i + 2) + ":AA" + (i + 2) + ")"
    if(selected[i] == supName[sCount]) finalArray[i][5] = "SELECTED";
    else finalArray[i][5] = "NOT SELECTED";
    Logger.log("B\n" + prodArray[i]);
```

This is the fullcode, the only thing that I cut are the sheetIDs.

```
function setMarketplace(){
  var itemCount = centralSh.getLastRow() - 1;
  var prodData = centralSh.getRange(2,1,itemCount, 5).getValues();

  var initArray = new Array(itemCount);
  var prodArray = new Array(itemCount);
  for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++){
    prodArray[i] = new Array(6)
    initArray[i] = new Array(4);

    initArray[i][0] = prodData[i][0];
    for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++){
      initArray[i][c + 1] = prodData[i][c + 2];
    }

    prodArray[i] = initArray[i];
    prodArray[i][4] = "=VLOOKUP(A" + (i + 2) + ";NL!A:E;5;0)";
    prodArray[i][5] = "=VLOOKUP(A" + (i + 2) + ";BE!A:E;5;0)";
  }

  for(var msfNumCount = 0; msfNumCount < 2; msfNumCount++){
    Logger.log("Starting with MSF " + msfName[msfNumCount])
    var msfSh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(msfID[msfNumCount]).getSheetByName("Supplier Selection " + msfName[msfNumCount]);

    Logger.log("Fetching Data Source")
    var msfCount = msfSh.getLastRow();
    var msfData = msfSh.getRange(2,1,msfCount, 7).getValues();

    Logger.log("Rearranging Data")
    var selected = new Array(itemCount);
    for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++){
      for (var j = 0; j < msfCount; j++){
        if(prodData[i][0] == msfData[j][0]){
          selected[i] = msfData[j][6];
          j = msfCount;
        }
      }
    }

    var finalArray = new Array(itemCount)
    for (var sCount = 0; sCount < supName.length; sCount++){

      if (msfNumCount == 0){
        var shProd = SpreadsheetApp.openById(supSheet[sCount]).getSheetByName("Overview Percentages");
        shProd.getRange(2,1,itemCount,6).setValues(prodArray);
      }

      Logger.log("Calculating Data for Supp " + sCount + " MSF " + msfName[msfNumCount])    

      for(var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++){
        finalArray[i] = new Array(6)
        finalArray[i] = initArray[i];

        Logger.log("A\n" + prodArray[i]);
        finalArray[i][4] = "=COUNTIF(F" + (i + 2) + ":AA" + (i + 2) + ";\"SELECTED\")/COUNTA(F" + (i + 2) + ":AA" + (i + 2) + ")"
        if(selected[i] == supName[sCount]) finalArray[i][5] = "SELECTED";
        else finalArray[i][5] = "NOT SELECTED";
        Logger.log("B\n" + prodArray[i]);
      }


      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(supSheet[sCount]).getSheetByName(msfName[msfNumCount]);

      Logger.log("Pasting Data for Supp " + sCount + " MSF " + msfName[msfNumCount]);   

      sh.getRange(2,1,itemCount,6).setValues(finalArray);
    }
  }
}
```

So yea I have no clue why this happens.

Comment: Can you share a copy of the data on the sheet to try it, or a dummy version of it?

Comment: Please share a copy of the original sheet and just explain what you are trying to do because your code is a mess.  It's probably a lot easier to do than you think